# Selenium doesn't open browser

Tags: java

I just started learning selenium using Java and I'm trying to run my first test but [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW2ar.png)Google chrome browser doesn't open and I get an error, could someone please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it? I have attached screenshots here, https://prnt.sc/80BUREDOXF5P , https://prnt.sc/-KlCUYpi4K_b [enter image description here](https://i.sta[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLYCW.png)ck.imgur.com/a9Yub.png)

I tried to run an automated test and I was excpecting google chrome to open but that didn't happen and I got an error

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the chromedriver executable file is not found or not accessible.